# Html display tables weirdly

Tags: html, css, flask

Since yesterday, i'm having a weird issue with my Flask projects. I'm following a tutorial and it's supposed to look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDHhP.png)

But it looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sorsg.png)

I've been looking for an answer since yesterday... any advice ?

Here is the code:
I have a base.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    {%block head%}{%endblock%}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for( 'static', filename='css/main.css')}}"
</head> 
<body>
    {%block body%} {%endblock%}
</body>
</html>
```

and a index.html that contains the table:

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}

{%block head%}

{%endblock%}



{%block body%}
<div class="content">
    <h1>Task Master</h1>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Added</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <a href="">Delete</a>
            <br>
            <a href="">Update</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
{%endblock%}
```

THANKS SO MUCH !

Comment: Looks like you set the borders to be invisible in your `main.css` file...

Comment: Yes, you lack the table border.

Comment: this is my main.css file code:
body{
    margin: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
it's the exact same as the instructor

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a second css file somewhere? It could also be there are other styles in the instructor's CSS that you haven't copied. For one thing, if you say your css is exactly the same as that of the instructor's, then your page should have a white background since the image from the tutorial has a white background. In fact that white background indicates there is some css somewhere else that is overriding the lightblue background color for the ```body```

Comment: The white background is me! I changed it to be sure that the css was linked properly.

Comment: Note that [main.css](https://github.com/jakerieger/FlaskIntroduction/blob/master/static/css/main.css) has plenty more styles, e.g. `table, td, th { border: 1px solid #aaa;}` Edit your question to include the full main.css you have

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.